# Listar pontos turísticos através da API Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

Eu no momento obrigo o utilizador a preencher a mão todos os pontos turísticos, fazendo um loop no código.

Contudo, eu queria saber como pegar essas informações dos pontos turísticos automaticamente, mais ou menos da forma que este hotel fez:
http://www.praiamarnatal.com.br/location.htm

Onde ele busca por categorias e faz a separação.

Answer (score 1):

O Google tem um API para isso, chamada Google Places API. Você encontra ela aqui: https://developers.google.com/places/?hl=pt-br

> As funções da biblioteca JavaScript do Google Places permitem que o
>   aplicativo pesquise locais (definidos nessa API como estabelecimentos,
>   localizações geográficas ou pontos de interesse proeminentes) contidos
>   em uma área definida, como os limites de um mapa ou a vizinhança de um
>   ponto fixo.

Essa API é bem completa, tem opções de obter places baseado numa determinada localização ou por tipo de lugar.

Comment: obrigado, vou dar uma olhada aqui

Comment: eu estou procurando na API, e nao encontro informações de exibir esses textos foram do Mapa. So consigo por essas informações dentro do mapa, queria por era numa página, por fora.

Comment: Acho que procuras pela places no proprio maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places - outra fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642418/trying-to-use-google-places-api-with-jquerys-getjson-function